# How to write to .txt file on remote server using HttpsUrlConnection in Android 9 Api 28

Tags: android

The code below is a sample from the Android Developers site that shows how to read .html site or .txt file using HttpsUrlConnection from remote server and works perfect in Android 9 Api28, but there is no sample showing how to write to .txt file using HttpsUrlConnection and my code which worked perfect in android 5,6,7,8 api 23,25,27 by using UrlConnection doesn't work in android 9 api 28 and I can't find any information how to fix it for android 9 Api 28.

```
// works perfect in android 9 api28
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {        
try{
URL url = new URL("https://somesite/test.txt");
res= downloadUrl(url);            
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {            
}
return null;
}
private String downloadUrl(URL url) throws IOException {
InputStream stream = null;
HttpsURLConnection  connection = null;
String result = null;
try {
connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();connection.setReadTimeout(3000);connection.setConnectTimeout(3000);connection.setRequestMethod("GET");connection.setDoInput(true);connection.connect();
int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
if (responseCode != HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
throw new IOException("HTTP error code: " + responseCode);
}
stream = connection.getInputStream();
if (stream != null) {
result = readStream(stream);
}
} finally {
if (stream != null) {
stream.close();
}
if (connection != null) {
connection.disconnect();
}
}
return result;
}
public String readStream(InputStream stream) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
Reader reader = null;
int readSize;
reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "cp1251");
char[] rawBuffer = new char[100000];
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
while (((readSize = reader.read(rawBuffer)) != -1)) {
buffer.append(rawBuffer, 0, readSize);
}
return buffer.toString();
}
// code which works perfect in android 5,6,7,8, but doesn't work in android 9 api 28
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {        
URLConnection connection;int timeout = 10000;   
URL url;
try {
url = new URL("ftp://username:password@somesite/test.txt");
connection = url.openConnection();            connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);connection.setReadTimeout(timeout);connection.setDoInput(true);connection.setDoOutput(true);connection.connect();
BufferedWriter out=new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(),"cp1251"));
out.write("some text");out.flush();out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
return null;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! "My code which worked perfect in android 5,6,7,8 api 23,25,27 by using UrlConnection doesn't work in android 9 api 28." - please clarify what means "doesn't work". What is the problem now with this code?

Comment: It means that it's  Restrictions on non-SDK interfaces. In general, apps should only use the officially documented parts of the classes in the SDK. In particular, this means that you should not plan to access
methods or fields that are not listed in the SDK when you interact with a class via semantics such as reflection.
That's why last part of my code above doesn't work in android9 Api28 it' depricated method and no sample how to write to file on remote server just how to read from file like I wrote above in first part of code.

Comment: you can read about it here

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces

Comment: and here the sample how to read from file using HttpsUrlConnection that I wrote above in first part of code. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting#java Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting#java

Comment: Downvoted: Not well-formated code (<del>even no indents!</del>even not using code block originally!), no detailed error (as @AlexYu pointed out, "please clarify what means "doesn't work"")

Comment: @GenoChen What would be your suggesions to improve OP question?

Comment: @AlexYu I posted an edit of indented code (waiting for peer review), and waiting for a clarification about "doesn't work" from author, for example a logcat or stacktrace.

Comment: logcat
2019-02-16 23:29:16.313 3099-3099/? W/.hitech.testal: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2019-02-16 23:29:16.314 3099-3099/? W/.hitech.testal: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-02-16 23:29:16.347 3099-3180/? D/MyTAG: Write to Url
2019-02-16 23:29:16.348 3099-3180/? D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

Comment: 2019-02-16 23:29:16.172 3099-3099/? W/.hitech.testal: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
2019-02-16 23:29:16.181 3099-3099/? I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
2019-02-16 23:29:16.194 3099-3099/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process

Comment: 2019-02-16 23:29:16.078 3099-3143/? I/.hitech.testal: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2019-02-16 23:29:16.170 3099-3099/? W/.hitech.testal: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
2019-02-16 23:29:16.172 3099-3099/? I/chatty: uid=10181(pro.hitech.testall) identical 10 lines

Comment: 2019-02-16 23:29:15.990 3099-3099/? I/.hitech.testal: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2019-02-16 23:29:16.071 3099-3136/? E/.hitech.testal: Unable to peek into adb socket due to error. Closing socket.: Connection reset by peer

Comment: Don't append information by comment. Besides, you are adding nothing useful. And you are rolling back the indents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Android 9 clear text traffic is prohibited. You will manually need to allow it adding below code to manifest.

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

Also, create *xml/network_security_config.xml* file and add below code to allow clear text traffic:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```